# In Java, static variable set() method using 'this' doesn't show any compilation issue

Tags: java, variables, static

```
 class SuperClass{
        static int x = 15;

        public void setX(int x){ 
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getX(){
            System.out.println(x);
            return x;
        }

    }


public class StaticVariableExample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SuperClass sc1= new SuperClass();
        sc1.setX(3);

        SuperClass sc2= new SuperClass();       
        sc2.setX(4);

        SuperClass sc3= new SuperClass();       
        sc3.setX(5);

        // since X is static variable Each instance of class calling add() and all instances will have same value even
        // assigned different values 3 4 5
        sc1.getX();
        sc2.getX();
        sc3.getX();
    }
}
```

X is static variable. Calling setX() doesn't give neither compilation nor runtime. It is behaving similar to normal variable Set(). Can u please explain why x setX() is working?

Comment: When referencing a static variable or method, <reference>.<memberName> is equivalent to <declared_type_of_reference>.<memberName>.

Answer (score 3):

Static members (variables and methods ) are allowed to be accessed by objects.

`this` refers to the current object and hence using current object reference, java allows to access static variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's working specifically because the static field isn't `final`.  If it were, then you couldn't assign anything to it again once it had been already assigned (as evidenced by `setX()`).

`this` always refers to the current object - and since `x` is in the current object, `this` knows where to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

If I have the class...

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static int x;
    public static void doIt() {
        System.out.println("x is " + x);
    }
}
```

And in some other class...

```
SomeClass ref = null;
ref.x = 5;
ref.doIt();
```

(Note that `ref` is set to `null`!)

The result will be that "x is 5" will be printed.

The point is that, when referencing a static member, the compiler will, if presented with a reference as the "base pointer", substitute the declared type of the reference.